# Render data from array of object based on a particular property as a heading in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of object like below -

```
{
   name:"Thor",
   universe:"Marvel",
   type:"God"
},
{
   name:"Batman",
   universe:"DC",
   type:"Human"
},
{
   name:"Iron man",
   universe:"Marvel",
   type:"Human"
},
];
```

Now, let's suppose that I want to render the objects such that the details of type **Human** are together, and the details of type **God** are together.

Basically, I want to display data based on the **type** property like below -

```
**Human**
name: Batman   universe:DC
name: Iron man universe:Marvel

**God**
name: Thor universe: Marvel
```

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-17-forked-u4nh9u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can help you with classification.
You can do render your self.

```
const data=[{
   name:"Thor",
   universe:"Marvel",
   type:"God"
},
{
   name:"Batman",
   universe:"DC",
   type:"Human"
},
{
   name:"Iron man",
   universe:"Marvel",
   type:"Human"
},
];
const category={};
for(let i of data){
category[i.type]??=[]
category[i.type].push(i)
}
```

Category like:

```
{
   "God":[
      {
         "name":"Thor",
         "universe":"Marvel",
         "type":"God"
      }
   ],
   "Human":[
      {
         "name":"Batman",
         "universe":"DC",
         "type":"Human"
      },
      {
         "name":"Iron man",
         "universe":"Marvel",
         "type":"Human"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am getting an error on nullish assignment as I am using TypeScript

Comment: Maybe typescript doesn't support that.
Try change
`category[i.type]??=[]`
to
`if(!(i.type in category))
category[i.type]=[];`

Answer (score 1):

I would first format the data type to an easy to use data type:
See example below:

```
function App() {
  const characters = [
    {
      name: "Thor",
      universe: "Marvel",
      type: "God",
    },
    {
      name: "Batman",
      universe: "DC",
      type: "Human",
    },
    {
      name: "Iron man",
      universe: "Marvel",
      type: "Human",
    },
  ];

  const charactersObj = {};
  characters.forEach((character) => {
    const { type } = character;
    if (charactersObj[type]) {
      const currentArray = [...charactersObj[type]];
      currentArray.push(character);
      charactersObj[type] = currentArray;
    } else {
      charactersObj[type] = [character];
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(charactersObj).map(([charType, charData]) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p> {charType}</p>
            {charData.map(({name, universe}) =>  <p>name: {name} universe: {universe} </p>)}
        
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one liner simple solution, it will work.

```js
const data = [{
    name: "Thor",
    universe: "Marvel",
    type: "God"
  },
  {
    name: "Batman",
    universe: "DC",
    type: "Human"
  },
  {
    name: "Iron man",
    universe: "Marvel",
    type: "Human"
  },
];

let obj = {
  Human: 1,
  God: 2
}

console.log(data.sort((a, b) => obj[a.type] - obj[b.type]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your data structure, you can just map over the type

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Human:
            <div>
                {heroes.map((hero) =>
                    hero.type === "Human" ? <div>{hero.name}</div> : null,
                )}
            </div>
            God:
            <div>
                {heroes.map((hero) =>
                    hero.type === "God" ? <div>{hero.name}</div> : null,
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: I can't hardcode Human and God... this is just a sample... there can be many tags

Comment: ...then you can just loop over all available types and do the same. this is just an example for your question. for each type you display the type, then map over your heroes and render only the ones with that type under that type label.

Comment: if for some reason you dont have access to all available types you can manually get the unique ones from your data by doing: 
const types = heroes.map((hero) => hero.type);
const uniqueTypes = new Set(types);

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```js
const data = [{
   name:"Thor",
   universe:"Marvel",
   type:"God"
},
{
   name:"Batman",
   universe:"DC",
   type:"Human"
},
{
   name:"Iron man",
   universe:"Marvel",
   type:"Human"
},
];

const transform = data => data.reduce((res, {type, ...rest}) => {

  return {
   ...res,
   [type]: [...(res[type] || []), rest]
  }

},{})

const toTemplate = (type, data) => {
return `**${type}**
${data.map(({name, universe}) => `name: ${name}   universe: ${universe}`).join('\n')}`
}
const toHtml = (data) => Object.entries(transform(data)).map(d => toTemplate(...d)).join('\n\n')

console.log(toHtml(data))
```